# Export DB2 DDL from One Cell in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: java, sql, google-sheets, db2

**I have a database change template to used by the team, it was accepted but the only thing needed is:**

1- Can we have syntax formatting for SQL within the same form?

2- How can we get only the DDL part out of this to generate a simple text field/file?

**Note:** This template will be used once per a month and it will have all the database changes, I'm looking for a way to make the syntax to be formatted like the SQL format, and is there a way where I could extract or Export only the queries to one text file even programmatically by using java or any similar programming language.

*Please advice and thank you.*

[image]

Comment: Howdy! I've been studying your question, but I don't understand it fully. I get that you want to get the cell that contains the DDL script, is that correct? If so, do you want to use Apps Script or any supported language on the Sheets API? In addition to that, could you please clarify what you mean with «syntax formatting for SQL within the same form»?

Comment: @Jacques-Guzel Heron : Thank you so much for your response. To explain it more, I have the Google sheet and I want my team to put there DDL changes in that sheet for the upcoming deployment. When it is time to review the DDLs, I want to be able to Extract only the DDLs out of the sheet into a text or CSV file format. This always happened twice or three times per a month. 
Yes I would love to learn something new and apply it  no matter what it is. I just need this to be running nicely and no time to be wasted when getting the data out of the Spreadsheet

Comment: @Jacques-Guzel Heron : For the "syntax formatting for SQL within the same form", when pasting the DDL on a spreadsheet, it does not recognize that this is a SQL syntax; it just deals with it as if it is a regular text. You may try to use Notepad++ and see how can you choose the syntax, Also Jira software does the same. It just need to recognize that this is a SQL query instead of a regular text.

Comment: There is no way to format SQL code in a cell, but there is a way to extract that cell value. To do it you could use [`Values.get()`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) from the Sheets API. Does it fix your issue? If so please confirm what language are you using so I can help you to include the API in your code.

Comment: @Jacques-Guzel Heron, Thank you so much for your help and support.
Yes I will be using Java, JavaScript, Or jQuery. Please let me know which one will be easier to implement the Sheets API with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments I understand that you want to capture a cell value by using [`Values.get()`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get). You can easily do that by following a quickstart tutorial (available on [Java](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) and [Node.js](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) as requested). That will help you to set up a working environment with Sheets API. After completing it, you only have to update the code to include [`Values.get()`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get). Please ask me any additional doubt if required.